# C#: How to access static variable in 'parent' class from another class

Tags: c#, class, variables

Ok so I have a simple program that I am trying to create which basically has two classes in it - `bird` and `egg`. In the `Program` class I set up a `list` of `bird` and a `list` of `egg` - both of which are declared above the `main` method in the `Program` class. The `bird` object has a method called `layEgg` which I want to add a new `egg` object to the `list` of `egg`. But I am not really sure how to access a `list` from a parent class.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can we have a code sample so we can fully understand the context?

Comment: Can you please provide an outline of the parent class? At least the place where the list is declared.

Comment: Is the list public? ie., public List<Eggs> eggs; ?

Comment: Why can't you just do:egglist.add(birdlist[0].layEgg());

Comment: The question should include the code you're trying to make work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you call *parent class* is not really a parent class. This is, you don't mean that class `bird` inherits from that parent class; you mean that it is declared **inside** that class. Such as this:

```
class Program
{
  private class egg { }

  private static List<egg> listOfEggs;

  private class bird
  {
    public void layEgg()
    {
      // How to access listOfEggs from here?
    }
  }

  private static List<bird> listOfBirds;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Initialise the lists, then:
    listOfBirds[0].layEgg();
  }
}
```

If so, the answer is really easy: `listOfBirds` can be accessed directly, since it is perfectly visible inside class `bird` even though everything is `private`:

```
  private class bird
  {
    public void layEgg()
    {
      listOfEggs.Add(new egg()); // No problem
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry getting my technical terminology mixed up. I did mean declared inside. Ill try your code now. Cheers

Comment: Oh dear, I know what I was doing wrong now and its embarrassing :-/ I was defining the bird/egg class outside of the program class <hangs head in shame>

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems like your approach is wrong. Try this:

```
namespace BirdsAndEggs
{
    public class Bird
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Egg> Eggs { get; set; }
    }
    public class Egg
    {
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        List<Bird> TheBirds = new List<Bird>();

        void main()
        {
            TheBirds.Add(new Bird()
            {
                Name = "Bird 1"
            });
            TheBirds.Add(new Bird()
            {
                Name = "Bird 2"
            });
            TheBirds.Add(new Bird()
            {
                Name = "Bird 3"
            });

            layEgg(0, "Large");
            layEgg(1, "Medium");
            layEgg(2, "Small");
        }

        void layEgg(int i, string size)
        {
            TheBirds[i].Eggs.Add(new Egg() { Size = size });
        }
    }
}
```

I mean, this is a really random guess at what you want, and I don't even know how familiar you are with C#... :/